# React - Having trouble with my redux user state not saving after reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux to save, in store, information based on if a user has signed in, or needs to sign in.

With this data, I declare if a Sign-in button needs to be shown in the header (if a user is not signed in, then the button needs to appear. If a user is signed in, then the button is replaced with a profile avatar).

The code only works during initial login moment, meaning the sign-in button is visible and then replaced by the user avatar for one second. After the user is `.push`'d to the homepage, the login button appears, even though they have successfully logged in. The state of the redux is not being stored?

**store.js**

```
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user:userReducer,
    },
})
```

**userSlice.js**

I slice a successfully logged in user:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        user: null
    },
    reducers: {
        login: (state, action) =>
        {
            state.user = action.payload;
        },
        logout: (state) =>
        {
            state.user = null;
        },
    },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**login.js**

Here is how I dispatch the data received from my login form:

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(formData);
        
            axiosInstance
                .post(`auth/token/`, {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: formData.email,
                    password: formData.password,

                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                    history.push('/');
                    window.location.reload();
                    dispatch(login({
                     name: formData.email,
                     password: formData.password,
                     loggedIn: true,
                   }))
                })
        };
```

**index.js**

I use `<Provider store={store}>` and wrap it around my routes.

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyThemeProvider>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
              </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </MyThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**header.js**

I have my button and user avatar located in my header:

```
function Header() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const user = useSelector(selectUser);

    const handleLogout = (e) =>
    {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(logout());
    };

    
    const displayDesktop = () => {
        return <Toolbar className={classes.toolBar}>
                    <Link
                        component={NavLink}
                        to="/"
                        underline="none"
                        color="textPrimary"
                    >
                       {Logo}
                    </Link>
                    <div>{getMenuButtons()}</div>
                      <div className={classes.profileAvatar}>   
                         {user ? getUserAccount() : loginButton()}
                         <Switch
                         checked={isDarkMode}
                         onChange={toggleDarkMode}
                         />
                    </div> 
                </Toolbar>;
      };
```

The statement that declares if a user is logged in or has to sign-in:

```
{user ? getUserAccount() : loginButton()}
```

just incase, this is how I implement it with my logout link:

```
                <MenuItem>
                component={NavLink}
                to="/logout" 
                onClick={function(event){ handleClose(); handleLogout()}}
                >
                Logout
                </MenuItem>
```

Please let me know how I can save the state of my redux `user` to be persistent until the logout button is used. If I'm missing code to help solve the bug, kindly let me know and I will edit this post. Thank you dearly for the help.

Just to state, the code does only work for 1 second, after a user logs in, but then the "sign in" button re-appears after page refresh/`push`.

EDIT: turns out this: `window.location.reload();` was one of the culprits, however the issue still persists as the data is not loading. The reload was just causing the page to instantly refresh upon login, which was making me loose my state.